# Dilemma whether it is MOLD on kombucha with green section

Tags: fermentation, secondary-fermentation, kombucha, mold

I am in the process of making my third batch of `Kombucha` and ingredients that I have used were

1. Darjeeling Black Tea
2. Darjeeling Green Tea
3. SCOBY (of course)

***Note: i haven't flavored yet***

Now, the issue is for my third batch I am a little worried about the health of my `SCOBY` as when today (after exactly 7 days ) when I opened the jar to check on it, i suspected small green area near the circumferences of my `SCOBY`. I am in a total dilemma now whether it's a `MOLD` or not.

Hence if anyone could help me in identifying by looking at the following pictures then it would really help me in deciding whether to keep this batch or discard.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I’ve been brewing Kombucha for 2 years now and have never had anything like that on my Scoby. I’d dump it and not take any chances.